# Sustituir valores al resultado de una consulta mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

tengo una consulta muy sencilla en mysql.

```
$consulta = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tabla where zona='$zona' and fecha between '$fecha_ini' and '$fecha_fin' order by fecha, $identificador asc;";
```

Esta consulta me trae el siguiente resultado.

```
Fecha           PML
4/6/2022 1:00   1620.87
4/6/2022 2:00   1848.88
4/6/2022 3:00   1861.35
4/6/2022 4:00   1670.13
4/6/2022 5:00   1664.17
4/6/2022 6:00   1718.06
4/6/2022 7:00   1730.49
4/6/2022 8:00   1614.89
4/6/2022 9:00   1184.29
4/6/2022 10:00  1288.05
4/6/2022 11:00  1250.8
4/6/2022 12:00  1178.87
4/6/2022 13:00  1208.99
4/6/2022 14:00  1182.18
4/6/2022 15:00  1179.12
4/6/2022 16:00  1378.58
4/6/2022 17:00  1309.61
4/6/2022 18:00  1839.72
4/6/2022 19:00  1707.18
4/6/2022 20:00  2237.38
4/6/2022 21:00  2704.19
4/6/2022 22:00  2777.22
4/6/2022 23:00  2357.58
4/6/2022 0:00   2051.8
```

con esto saco una grafica.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los controles tengo una opcion que es horario SOLAR, este horario me cambia el query y solamente me traer los datos en un rango de horario de 7 hrs a 19 hrs.

```
$consulta = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tabla where zona='$zona' and fecha between '$fecha_ini' and '$fecha_fin'and hora between '7' and '19' order by fecha, $identificador asc;";
```

y me trae estos valores, sin las otras 12 hrs.

```
Fecha               PML
2022-04-06 07:00:00 1730.49
2022-04-06 08:00:00 1614.89
2022-04-06 09:00:00 1184.29
2022-04-06 10:00:00 1288.05
2022-04-06 11:00:00 1250.8
2022-04-06 12:00:00 1178.87
2022-04-06 13:00:00 1208.99
2022-04-06 14:00:00 1182.18
2022-04-06 15:00:00 1179.12
2022-04-06 16:00:00 1378.58
2022-04-06 17:00:00 1309.61
2022-04-06 18:00:00 1839.72
2022-04-06 19:00:00 1707.18
2022-04-07 07:00:00 1280.98
2022-04-07 08:00:00 1270.56
2022-04-07 09:00:00 1354.97
2022-04-07 10:00:00 1289.46
2022-04-07 11:00:00 1237.86
2022-04-07 12:00:00 1247.28
2022-04-07 13:00:00 1295.82
2022-04-07 14:00:00 1242.86
2022-04-07 15:00:00 1329.12
2022-04-07 16:00:00 1411.83
2022-04-07 17:00:00 1311.29
2022-04-07 18:00:00 1430.63
2022-04-07 19:00:00 1401.02
```

La grafica cambia correctamente. Hasta ahi todo ok.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es, como puedo poner los demas valores en NULL que no tenga nada pero si esten las fechas ejemplo algo asi:

```
    Fecha           PML
    4/6/2022 1:00   
    4/6/2022 2:00   
    4/6/2022 3:00   
    4/6/2022 4:00   
    4/6/2022 5:00   
    4/6/2022 6:00   
    4/6/2022 7:00   1730.49
    4/6/2022 8:00   1614.89
    4/6/2022 9:00   1184.29
    4/6/2022 10:00  1288.05
    4/6/2022 11:00  1250.8
    4/6/2022 12:00  1178.87
    4/6/2022 13:00  1208.99
    4/6/2022 14:00  1182.18
    4/6/2022 15:00  1179.12
    4/6/2022 16:00  1378.58
    4/6/2022 17:00  1309.61
    4/6/2022 18:00  1839.72
    4/6/2022 19:00  1707.18
    4/6/2022 20:00  
    4/6/2022 21:00  
    4/6/2022 22:00  
    4/6/2022 23:00  
    4/6/2022 0:00
```

En la primera consulta me traigo las 24 dia y noche, al seleccionar horas solares son las horas entre las 7 y 19 hrs. Lo que requiero es traerme las horas solares y cambiar los valores diferentes a estas horas por espacio vacio para que no se grafiquen
Disculpen mi falta de experiencia, muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: No logro entender lo que quieres. En la 2ª consulta aplicas este criterio: `and hora between '7' and '19'` pero luego dices que quieres los horarios inferiores a ese rango, pero con valores `NULL`, ahora bien, ¿cuál es el criterio que aplica para que los valores sean `NULL` en horas inferiores a las 7 de la mañana? y, ¿por qué en la 1ª consulta que muestras hay datos en esas columnas? ¿Esos `NULL` que quieres son **reales** o son **ficticios**?

Comment: Hola en la primera consulta me traigo las 24 dia y noche, al seleccionar horas solares son las horas entre las 7 y 19 hrs. Lo que requiero es traerme las horas solares y cambiar los valores diferentes a estas horas por espacio vacio para que no se grafiquen, si es 0 no importa mucho por que la grafica grafica el 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, quieres un valor ficticio, para los datos cuyas horas no estén entre las `7` y las `19`. Eso **no puedes filtrarlo en el criterio del `WHERE`**, porque dicho filtro impediría que esas filas sean traídas. Tienes que quitar el `and hora between '7' and '19'` del `WHERE` y aplicarlo en el `SELECT` usando por ejemplo `CASE ... WHEN`.

Considera que la parte del `CASE ... WHEN` es una columna de tus resultados, por tanto, **debes poner explícitamente cada columna que quieres**. De hecho, así debería ser en todas las consultas. El famoso `SELECT *`, que aparece hasta en la sopa, debería ser una instrucción prohibida en entornos de aprendizaje ... luego, muchos programas finales quedan con esa instrucción, trayendo columnas que nunca se van a usar.

Algo así debería funcionar:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    fecha, 
    hora,
    CASE 
        WHEN hora BETWEEN '7' AND '19' THEN PML 
        ELSE NULL
    END AS PML
FROM tabla 
WHERE 
    zona='$zona' 
    AND fecha BETWEEN '$fecha_ini' AND '$fecha_fin'
ORDER BY fecha, $identificador ASC;
```

Simplemente en la consulta le estás diciendo: *si la hora está entre las 7 y las 19, traeme el valor de `PML`, de lo contrario, ponme un valor `NULL`*.

#### Algunas observaciones

1. No es una buena práctica almacenar fechas por una parte y horas por otra. Deberías guardar todo en una columna del tipo `DATETIME` y luego si quieres filtrar por la hora o por la fecha extraer esa parte. Por cada columna, usando `DateTime`, ahorrarás el 50% y muchos cálculos se simplificarán, ganando en rendimiento.
2. Con respecto al entorno PHP, tu forma de consulta, usando variables dentro de la consulta, constituye un gravísimo problema de seguridad llamado *inyección SQL*. Un usuario mal intencionado podría usar tu consulta para causar gravísimos daños en el servidor, o bien obtener/modificar/borrar información sensible o de cualquier otro tipo.

Comment: Como siempre me salva de mi falta de experiencia muchas gracias quedo justo como lo requeria, ya traigo un campo unix_date para la busqueda el campo hora solo me sirve para el acomodo de la consulta ya que las horas son del 0 al 23, lo que hacer es transformar el 0 en 24 para poder situarlo a la hora que le corresponde al final y queden del 1 al 24. Gracias Cedano grande!!!

Comment: @JoaquinDuran me alegro de que te haya servido. En mi Post-Data yo me refiero a que, en vez de tener dos columnas (`fecha` y `hora`) puedes una sola, donde guardes tanto la fecha como la hora y luego, si quieres diferenciar, puedes obtener la fecha o la hora de esa única columna. Declarando dos columnas, ocupas el doble de espacio para almacenar un dato que al fin y al cabo es el mismo.

Comment: Oooooooh!!! tienes toda la razon, el motivo por el cual esta asi, es por que el API de Gobernacion nos manda asi los datos, realmente las tablas son muy muy grandes una llega a pesar 5g y el fechaunix es el que me ayuda para que no sea tan lento la busqueda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de `replace()` y cambiar los capos vacios `("")` por `("NULL")` te dejo un ejemplo: https://www.sqlshack.com/es/una-descripcion-general-de-la-funcion-sql-replace/ , espero que te sirva de ayuda, saludos...

Comment: Hola, mil gracias por tu orientacion, el detalle es que no tengo ningun valor en 0 o null, dejame explico, quiero que me traiga los valores entre la hora 7 y 19, sustituyendo el valor de las demas horas por vacio para que no sea null ni 0 ya que el 0 lo graficaria